# How to resize video using ffmpeg in php without exec

Tags: php, ffmpeg, resize, exec

Is it possible to resize video using ffmpeg-php or something another library, because the server throws the error "Warning:  exec() has been disabled for security reasons in..."

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like exec() has been disabled in your hosts version of php. This can happen when you're on a shared hosting provider.

The exec() function execute an external program on Linux Shell or Windows CMD

So obviously this feature is disabled by the administrator of your hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pclose(popen($cmd, 'r')); instead exex() will help